# Pull value from Kivy Spinner

Tags: spinner, kivy, assign, pull

We have a spinner in our code and need to assign a value to the selection so we can use it later.

```
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            font_size: '48sp'
            text: "[color=000000][sub]Select a sport:[/sub][/color]"
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'middle'
            markup: True
            text_size: self.size

        Spinner:
            text: 'Select a sport'
            values: ('Soccer', 'Basketball', 'Volleyball', 'Handball')
            size: (100,44)
```

Answer (score 0):

The spinner gives several options that, when selected, will *replace* its `text`. So if you select 'Basketball', its text property will be `'Basketball'`. You can access the value this way.